# How do I make this entire search box smaller?

Tags: css

I'm using a Wordpress theme with a MLS search box however the search box is too large for my client and they want us to reduce the size of this entire search box. I've been playing with it but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Site is http://shouldirentorbuyahome.com/

```
}

/*-------------------------------------
4.3 Advance Search
-------------------------------------*/

.advance-search-block { background:#F2F2F2; padding:5px 0 10px; position:relative; }
.advance-search-block label { display:block; font-weight:200; font-size:12px; color:#384042; margin-bottom:10px; }
.advance-search-block ul { width: 80%; }
.advance-search-block ul li { float:left; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:15px; }
.advance-search-block input[type='text'] { font-size:10px; color:#777; padding:8px 8px 9px; width:75px; border:1px solid #E1E1E1; }
.advance-search-block select.small, .advance-search-block a.small { width:150px !important; }
.advance-search-block input[type='submit'] { background:#445064; color:#FFF; padding:8px 11px; font-size:12px; font-weight:200; cursor:pointer; }
.advance-search-block input[type='submit']:hover { background:#344053; }
.search-title { position:absolute; top:0px; }
.search-title h4 { background:#445064; padding:18px 25px; font-size:12px; font-weight:200; float:left; color:#FFF; margin-bottom:0; }
.search-title span { float:left; display:block; background:#88C354; color:#FFF; font-size:12px; padding:18px 20px; }
.advance-search-block.advance-search-block-page { background:none; padding:0; margin-top:-200px; }
.advance-search-block.advance-search-block-page .inside { background:#dcecce; background:rgba(220,236,206,0.8); padding:30px 30px 0; width:1020px;  }
.advance-search-block.advance-search-block-page ul li { margin-right:15px; }
.advance-search-block.advance-search-block-page input[type="text"] { width:150px; }
.advance-search-block.advance-search-block-page .search-title { position:relative; top:0; }
.advance-search-block.advance-search-block-page .search-title h4 { background:none; padding:0; font-size:12px; color:#384042; }
.advance-search-block.advance-search-block-page .search-title span { 
    background:#445064; padding:4px 8px; margin-right:15px; border-radius:50%; -webkit-border-radius:50%; -moz-border-radius:50%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
.advance-search-block.advance-search-block-page input[type="text"] { width:150px; }
```

Can't you just change the width of this element to something not as wide?

Suggest

```
.advance-search-block.advance-search-block-page input[type="text"] { width:60%; }
```

Give that a shot and I'm sure you know in wordpress you will need to manually update your styles.css.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong you are talking about that blue button?
Your blue submit button has a div and it has a class 'dsidx-search-button search-form' with width of `1020px !important` , reduce it to `250px !important` as per your requirement.